# Не получается получить атрибут динамически загруженного элемента

Tags: php, jquery

Мне нужно получить значение атрибута класса `confirm`, который динамически формируется через post запрос к БД. При попытке его получить, выводит `undefined`, хотя в консоли значение этого атрибута отображается.

```
function tasksout() { //Вывод задач пользователю
    $.post(
        "core.php", 
        {
            "action" : "taskout"
        }, 
        function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var out = '';
            if(data!="0"){
              for (var i in data) {
                out +=`<div class="task" data-id="${i}">`
                out +=`<div class="sender"><p>Отправитель:</p>${data[i].sender}</div>`;
                out +=`<div class="titlee"><p>Заголовок:</p>${data[i].title}</div>`;
                out +=`<div class="msg"><p>Сообщение:</p>${data[i].msg}</div>`;
                out +=`</div>`
                out +=`<div class="confirm" data-id="${i}">Подтвердить выполнение</div>`
                }
              }
              else{
                out +=`<div class="task id="0"><p>Задач не найдено</p></div>`
              }
            $('.tasks').html(out);
          }
    );
}
```

Атрибут пытаюсь получить таким образом

```
  var id = $('.confirm').attr('data-id');
  console.log(id);
```

[image: Консоль]

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", '.confirm', function() {
  var id = $('.confirm').attr('data-id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

Решение